# Не меняется тема в приложении Android на axml

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Пытаюсь убрать верхнюю строку с названием приложения и поменять тему с черной на белую с помощью параметра

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

в теге `LinearLayout`, но тема и строка так и остаются прежними. В чем моя ошибка?

Весь код XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
```

Код MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

namespace XTA
{
    [Activity(Label = "XTA", MainLauncher = true)]
  public class MainActivity : Activity
  {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Можно код activity?

Comment: Прошу прощения за свою неосведомленность, ведь я являюсь еще новичком в Xamarin... Однако я не знаю где могу просмотреть этот код.

Comment: Код главного экрана.

Comment: Весь код главного экрана уже приложен в вопросе.

Comment: У вас есть класс `MainActivity.cs`?

Comment: Уже добавил код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите стиль из разметки и в стилях поменяйте тему на:

```
Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar
```